# How to convert HH:MM:SS time to decimal in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

Assuming that I have the following date and time **(June 12, 2017 07:10:43.340)** that I stored in a `dateime` object. From that I have a `timestamp` object, as follows:

```python
from datetime import *

timeH = datetime(2017, 6,12, 7, 10, 43, 340)
timeHstamp = timeH.timestamp()
```

What I want to obtain is a decimal representation of the time only. That is
`7.178` which I calculated, manually, by dividing seconds over 60 **(43.34/60)**, add it the minutes **(10+0.7223)**, divide the total minutes by 60 **(10.7223/60)**, and then add to hours **(7+0.178)**. I know I can write a custom function that would output exactly what I need. However, I am wondering if there is any available methods that can achieve this.

I have searched stackoverflow and other sites; but, there doesn't seem to be function that does this in Python. This post provide something similar but in Matlab [Convert hh:mm time to decimal time (Matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65358970/convert-hhmm-time-to-decimal-time-matlab)

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098248/time-to-decimal-time-in-python

Comment: I checked that post. It is NOT what I am asking here.  The post does not use any built-in function that solve the issue as I explained. Thanks.

Comment: What must you use a built-in function, if one does not exist?

Comment: @blhsing This is exactly what I am asking: Is there a built-in function (that someone know of and I am not aware of)?

Comment: No there is not. All Python time functions return numeric time in the unit of seconds. A simple conversion of `timeH.timestamp() / 3600 % 24` would be way too trivial to be made into a separate built-in function.

Comment: @blhsing that will give you fractional hours UTC since Unix time refers to UTC - if the OP has a datetime object that represents local time (or some specific time zone), you'd have to replace the tzinfo with timezone.utc - which I think might be hard to understand for future readers of the code ^^

Answer (score 3):

One way using `datetime.combine`:

```
(datetime.combine(date.min, timeH.time()) - datetime.min).total_seconds()/3600
```

Output:

```
7.178611205555555
```